# PostgreSQL, Npgsql returning 42601: syntax error at or near "$1"

Tags: postgresql, dapper, npgsql

I'm trying to use Npgsql and/or Dapper to query a table and I keep running into `Npgsql.PostgresException 42601: syntax error at or near "$1".`

Here is what I've got trying it with NpgsqlCommand:

```
  using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["postgres"].ConnectionString))
  {
    conn.Open();
    using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from Logs.Logs where Log_Date > current_date - interval @days day;", conn))
    {
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@days", days);
      var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

I've also tried it with Dapper(my preferred method) with:

```
  using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["postgres"].ConnectionString))
  {
    conn.Open();
    var logs = conn.Query<Log>("select * from Logs.Logs where Log_Date > current_date - interval @days day;", new {days = days});
```

Either way I get the same `Npgsql.PostgresException  42601: syntax error at or near "$1" error.`  The Statement in the Exception shows: `select * from Logs.Logs where Log_Date > current_date - interval $1 day`

Note, if I do the following it works fine, but it's not properly parameterized:

```
var logs = conn.Query<Log>("select * from Logs.Logs where Log_Date > current_date - interval '" + days + "' day;");
```

What am I doing wrong?  I very much appreciate any feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't allow you to stick a parameter anywhere in a query. What you want can be achieved with the following:

```
var command = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from Logs.Logs where Log_Date > current_date - @days", conn))
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@days", TimeSpan.FromDays(days));
```

This way you're passing the interval directly from Npgsql to PostgreSQL, rather than a part of the expression designed to create that interval.

Comment: Awesome, that did it.  I knew it had to be something simple, just couldn't quite figure it out.  Thanks.

Comment: Is it still the case in Npgsql 8.0.2 (EF 8)? I have this query: `_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSql($"GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO {roleName}")` and it throws the same error. So I assume Npgsql doesn't support parameterized queries?

Answer (score 5):

i got this error using DapperExtensions

adding

```
DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.SqlDialect = new PostgreSqlDialect();
DapperAsyncExtensions.SqlDialect = new PostgreSqlDialect();
```

before creating the connection fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

To subtract days from a date (assuming `log_date` is data type `date`), you can simplify:

```
"SELECT * FROM logs.logs WHERE log_date > CURRENT_DATE - @days;"
```

And provide `@days` as unquoted numeric literal (digits only) - which is taken to be an `integer`. This is even more efficient, since `date` - `integer` returns `date`, while `date` - `interval` returns `timestamp`.

[The manual about interval input.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT)