# PostgreSQL, Npgsql returning 42601: syntax error at or near “$1”

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection, psql, npgsql

While passing PostgreSQL command following error

> 42601: syntax error at or near "$1"

```
using (Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection conn = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(DBManager.GetConnectionString()))
            {
                conn.Open();
                Logger.Info("connection opened for adding column");
                using (Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand addColumnQuery = new Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand(@"ALTER TABLE @tableName ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS @columnName  @columnType;", conn))
                {
                    addColumnQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", tableName);
                    addColumnQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnName", columnName);
                    addColumnQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnType", columnType);
                    addColumnQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL, Npgsql returning 42601: syntax error at or near "$1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752836/postgresql-npgsql-returning-42601-syntax-error-at-or-near-1). Also I'm not sure that it is possible [to use parameter for the table name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44023111/940182) in the `NpgsqlCommand`

Comment: @oleksa i tried without table name, still i got same error. I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: try to put sql command without parameters, with table, column and type names in the command text and check will it work or not. Like `ALTER TABLE testTableName ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS testColumnName  int;`. Then you can add parameters one by one (starting from column type e.g.) to check what causes the error.

Comment: @oleksa thanks for the help. Is that the correct way for passing parameter?

Comment: yes if it is not about table name :) Please check [the sample](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Npgsql/NpgsqlCommand/-/php-npgsqlcommand-class-examples.html#0xfc3aa28244dc61caa080ca74f296ea16bbf7bba539f988b6307dacdd9518b35e-49,,82,) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950406/940182).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I found that only table values can be passed as parameter not table name and column name. So I changed code like this

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN columnName columnType;
```